# How do you prevent protected members of the base class from still being accessed in the second level of the subclass?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, protected

An example to illustrate my problem:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int x{ 0 };
};

class DerivedClass1 : public Base
{
};

class DerivedClass2 : public DerivedClass1
{
public:
    int getX() const
    {
        return x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedClass2 d2{};
    int x{ d2.getX() };
    return 0;
}
```

I can access the protected member of `Base` in the`DerivedClass2` class, although the protected members of `Base` should only be changed in `DerivedClass1`. By inheriting the variable in `Base` to `DerivedClass1` a class shall be formed, which the `DerivedClass2` must not manipulate. In C# this is possible with the `private protected` keyword, but how can you handle it in C++?

Comment: Protected data is almost always a bad idea. Simply, don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - hmm ok.

Comment: FWIW, the C# `private protected` access level doesn't really do what you want, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What are the consequences of protected?

It is the very idea of `protected` to allow all the derived classes to access such members.

While this is a very flexible language feature, it creates a serious weakness in the encapsulation, which encourages breaking the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (more precisely the history constraint, since a derived class could alter the state of a base object without going through a base class primitive).

#### How to avoid its drawbacks ?

If you want a stronger encapsulation and restrictive access, you'd need to go to `private`.  This ensure that the inner state of a base class can only be accessed using the public interface. (Note that while it ensures the history constraint, it doesn't on its own guarantee LSP).  And the consequence is that no derived class gets access. Not at first derivation, and not later.

#### Do you need private protected ?

What you want, is a kind of in-between:  a weak encapsulation, but not too weak.  This doesn't exist in C++.  And I'm not sure it would strengthen your design.

But if you need this limitation on exceptional basis, there could be a work-around, playing with the name lookup:

```
class DerivedClass1 : public Base
{
private:
    using Base::x; 
// In DerivedClass1 you can still use x.
};

// But it will fail to compile in Derived2
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/kHCHS4)

But personally I would not advise to go this way.  It's error prone (you could forget the `using` in one sibling derived).  The compiler error messages might be misleading.  And anyway,  private yields more robust design.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the data member as `private` and use `friend`-declarations to explicitly specify which classes may access it though:

```
class Base
{
    friend class DerivedClass1;
private:
    int x = 0;
};

class DerivedClass1 : public Base
{
    void test() {
        cout << x;  // OK: DerivedClass1 is a friend of Base
    }
};

class DerivedClass2 : public DerivedClass1
{
public:
    int getX() const
    {
        return x;  // ERROR: x is a private member
    }
};
```

Comment: That's right, thanks. That would be a compromise solution, of course.

Comment: Indeed, this is also a possible work-around.  Its main drawback is that it forces a strong coupling between `Base` and `Derived`, and in particular, `Base` needs to know about all its potential first degree derivates.  Not really [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open–closed_principle)-friendly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Inherit a 'private' Base:

```
class DerivedClass1 : private Base
{

};
```

Edit: Expose public or protected members in *Base* through public or protected members in *DerivedClass1*. *DerivedClass1* then has complete control over what *Base* members can and cannot be accessed by classes inheriting from *DerivedClass1*.

Whether that's a good solution depends on the complexity of *Base*.

Comment: This is of course a solution, but this only works if the `base` class has no public members. Thx:)

Comment: True; those members would need to be exposed through public or protected methods in DerivedClass1.